# how to add facebook plugin page to gatsby (react)

Tags: reactjs, facebook, iframe, gatsby

I have been trying to add facebook feed to a gatsby website that I'm working on and it doesn't seem to work!

I've tried to add the scripts in gatsby-ssr.js

```
const React = require("react")

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setPostBodyComponents([
    <div id="fb-root"></div>,
    <script
      async={true}
      defer={true}
      crossOrigin="anonymous"
      src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId=2186738638294469&autoLogAppEvents=1"
    ></script>,
  ])
}
```

then in component

```
          <div
            className="fb-page"
            data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TechnoBondCo/"
            data-tabs="timeline"
            data-width="400"
            data-height="400"
            data-small-header="true"
            data-adapt-container-width="true"
            data-hide-cover="true"
            data-show-facepile="false"
          >
            <blockquote
              cite="https://www.facebook.com/TechnoBondCo/"
              class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"
            >
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TechnoBondCo/">
                ‎تكنوبوند - صناع الكلادينج Techno Bond‎
              </a>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
```

but it didn't work, I also tried to use react-facebook but I cant seem to change the width or height of the iframe

any idea how to do this?

ERRORS USING REACT HELMET

I get this console error:
  - warn "export 'default' (imported as 'Helmet') was not found in 'react-helmet'

and get this browser error:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing FB.XFBML.parse https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: Hey @WizKid, i tried to call that in useEffect but it said that FB is not defined.

Comment: Then the Facebook SDK haven't been loaded yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `<Helmet>` tag, like this:

```
<Helmet>
    <script async={true} defer={true} crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId=2186738638294469&autoLogAppEvents=1" />
</Helmet>
```

You can check for further information about [Gatsby's Helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/), and [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet), but basically, `<Helmet>` component allows you to insert a few code that will be placed after compilation inside the `<head>` tag.

You can use it in any component, for example, in `IndexPage` component it would be:

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

     const IndexPage = () => (
        <Layout>
          <SEO title="Live" />
          <Helmet>
            <script async={true} defer={true} crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId=2186738638294469&autoLogAppEvents=1" />
          </Helmet>
```

I've tested in my local machine it loads perfectly as it shows the following screenshot:

[image: Script loaded]

Comment: I was trying your answer and get a weird error! I updated the question with it, do you mind explaining the reason for it?

Comment: You need to import like this `import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';` I've edited my answer. Usually, that error comes from a bad module importation.

Comment: the error was from another file I had helmet on but it wasn't imported the right way haha my bad, the answer did indeed work but the iframe is pretty small! any idea how can I pass my own height and width to it? because I have it right now but it doesn't work!

Comment: Have you tried with CSS or SCSS styles? Checkout Facebook SDK documentation for that case. I've never used it. Anyway, you're one step further than a while ago.

Comment: I did but it didnt work because but thank you so much for your help! :)